# Re-building new LDAP from old one?

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap

OS is CentOS7.
LDAP is OpenLDAP.

I have a situation concerning old LDAP. Is it possible to bring it up, as there are some files I need to get to.

So, lets summarize, I have backup of whole old server, but I need some files from old server, or even set-up new LDAP and somehow merge new and old LDAP. Is it possible?

Please don't be harsh on me, I'm trying to learn..

Comment: About what ldap server in question? OpenLDAP? 389-ds? Or any other? (There is no difference which Web server you use.)

Comment: how do I check that?  '# ldap -h
bash: ldap: command not found'

Comment: I have backup of OLD LDAP, but I think there is no instalation of new LDAP.

Comment: A backup of whiсh LDAP server you have? "OLD" does not look like ldap server program name.

Comment: i tried locating it with 'locate'- # locate ldap
/etc/openldap
/etc/sudo-ldap.conf
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-ldap.conf.ext
/etc/openldap/certs
/etc/openldap/ldap.conf
/etc/openldap/certs/cert8.db
/etc/openldap/certs/key3.db
/etc/openldap/certs/password
/etc/openldap/certs/secmod.db
/etc/php.d/ldap.ini
/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/ldap.pp

Comment: i think it's openldap, as 'locate' found

Comment: You will find the common files present in most systems - does not necessarily indicate the presence of LDAP server.

Comment: If you do not know which backups you have, I'm afraid then serverfault will be one more unanswered question.

Comment: ok, i think wasn't clear...i don't have ldap server running NOW. i have a backup of old ldap. i was thinking to install new ldap and to migrate data form old to new one. reason is that on the old server i have some encrypted files i would ilke to get to. former web admin left all the passwords in folders, but i don't know which is one. main reason is i want to get owncloud back up&runnin' so i could get to these encrypted files. so i tought the easyest eay is to install new ldap, new owncloud and get those data.

Comment: openldap-servers-2.4.39

Comment: Whether you want to restore data from a backup LDAP server? Or sufficient to get a new LDAP configuration and schemes like the old?

Comment: i want to restore library on old owncloud (1000+ books). so, i belive i need to install new ldap to migrate data (users, files). maybe you have a better idea? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Owncloud keeps your documents (books included) as simple files on the disk - you can try to find them in the backup and just copy to new server. There is no need to restore the LDAP, the more that you are bad you know how it works.**

However, (for example if you want to recreate your old server) you need to:

1. Install same openldap packages as in old system.
2. Copy the contents of `/opt/openldap/` folder from the backup copy in the same folder as the new system (with files replacement). Note To save the file owner and permissions.
3. Copy the contents of `/var/lib/ldap/` folder from the backup copy in the same folder as the new system (with files replacement). Note To save the file owner and permissions.

After this OpenLDAP server must run with the same configuration and data.

Perhaps there is a problem with the SSL certificate - if it was used.  Errors in OpenLDAP log (commonly `/var/log/ldap.log`) will help you with its decision.

Comment: hm...ok, i have the books. downloaded them. most of them are in .pdf. but can't open them because of the aes256. i don't have that key. or maybe i have it, but don't know where it could be. old admin was correct and saved those passwords in a folder i can reach. folder names are ldap-registrator, ldap-searcher, ldap-domain.com. ldap-forum and so on...maybe i can start the old one back?

Comment: In this case, you will need to restore from a backup the entire  owncloud including openldap (as I described) and  owncloud DB.

Comment: ok, tkank you. it will be a hell of a job but i got to start somewhere.